# Firebase unable to access data with "snapshot"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing a web application that uses Firebase, and reading information from the database structured like the following:

```
"user" : {
"-KcNmMmqbSvmVXx2vn4A" : {
  "email" : "firebase@firebase.com",
  "firstname" : "fire",
  "membership_tier" : 1,
  "session_count" : 0,
  "surname" : "base"
}
```

I'm attempting to read the number of sessions the user has undertaken - however no results are being returned.

What I've tried so far:

```
 firebase.database().ref('/users/' + uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
   var sessionCount = snapshot.val().session_count;
 });
```

Currently `snapshot.val()` is returning `null`. I'm getting an error stating:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'session_count' of null

`uid` has been defined, and therefore no issue should be had with accessing the user's information.

Any pointers would be massively appreciated!

Comment: When val() returns null, that means there is no data at the location that you queried.  Double check that your ref points to the correct path in the database that you want to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code shared by you, you have defined `user` in database but trying to access `users` which could cause the error that you are getting. Make sure you are using correct `ref`.

Answer (score 2):

The below works for me:

```
  //INITIALIZE FIREBASE WEB APP
  firebase.initializeApp(config); 
  var db = firebase.database();
  var auth = firebase.auth();

  db.ref('/whatever/').once('value').then(function(snap) {
    if(snap.val()){
      console.log(snap.val().whateverProperty);
    } else {
      console.log('/whatever/whateverProperty node does not exist!');
    }
  }, function(error) {
    // The Promise was rejected.
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Vivek was right that I hadn't used `user`, and would have also lead to an error, however the main issue was that the reading code resided within a function that had `database` passed to it, assigned to `firebase.database()`. Changing the code to this worked fine:

```
database.ref('/user/' + uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var sessionCount = snapshot.val().session_count;
});
```

Cheers for the pointers!